# HTML multiple forms in different sections

Tags: html

I have several sections in my page that I need to include under the same `form` tag, but doing so breaks the HTML. For example:

```
<div>
<form name="firstform">
    <input type="text" name="input1" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" />
    <input type="text" name="input3" />
</div>
<p>bla bla</p>
<div>
<form name="secondform">
    <input type="text" name="one" />
</form>

    <input type="text" name="input4">
</form>
```

So basically I want to submit the form `firstform` but in a way that will include `input4` but without submitting `secondform`?

**EDIT:**

I have a pretty long page with a lot of inputs, in the middle of the page I have a different form that is used to allow file upload which I want to keep where it is in the page, however, after that section I have a continuation of the first form. so I have the first form, then another form with the file upload and then the rest of the first form.

Comment: Just have one form tag then? You can't nest forms. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why not just wrap everything in a single form tag?

Comment: What about the other form in there? all input1-4 are wrapped in the same form tag

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm trying to submit ``firstform`` without submitting ``secondform`` even though it's nested in it.. possible?

Comment: Reading various discussions on this around the web, one idea is to have one form with 2 buttons then check which button was clicked and process accordingly. Would that solution work for you?

Comment: This is not possible, hence why you need to elaborate a little more on what exactly you're trying to achieve.  As has already been stated, forms cannot be nested, so there is a better way to do whatever it is you're aiming at.

Comment: You cannot nest forms. It's not allowed and your browser will try to fix you form by closing it before the next form is created. You should either wrap everything in a single form, use javascript to manage what gets submitted in the form, or use ajax to the same affect.

Comment: @JamesScholes I've just updated my question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple forms, use one form tag with multiple submit buttons. Give to the buttons name and value and its time a user submit the form, chech in the back end which button has been pushed.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add an html button with an onClick event that calls a function to mimic a nested form. If the second form's onSubmit function is pure javaScript this could be a quick cut/paste. If your second form is communicating with a server you'll have to jump into some AJAX.